# Executing a stored procedure to insert records into a table - SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2000. The following query is not working

```
declare @TempAccountKey Table (AccKey int,SitName varchar(1000),SitKey int) 
insert into @TempAccountKey(AccKey,AccName) 
exec [usp_Get_AccountForUser] @UserName
```

It is throwing the error

*EXECUTE cannot be used as a source when inserting into a table variable.*

Any ideas?

**#1**

---

The linked server is properly set up. If i execute the following query

```
exec [ABC-SQL-PROD.DBabc.dbo.usp_Get_ABCForUser]
```

it is showing the error 'Could not find stored procedure'.

Any ideas?

NLV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a temp table instead

```
CREATE TABLE #TempSiteKey (AccKey int,SitName varchar(1000),SitKey int) 

insert into #TempSiteKey (AccKey,AccName) 
exec [usp_Get_AccountForUser] @UserName 

DROP TABLE #TempSiteKey
```

And the reason you can't call the procedure is because you've delimited it incorrectly

```
exec [ABC-SQL-PROD.DBabc.dbo.usp_Get_ABCForUser]
```

Actually means execute the procedure called 'ABC-SQL-PROD.DBabc.dbo.usp_Get_ABCForUser'.

What you want is:

```
exec [ABC-SQL-PROD].[DBabc].[dbo].[usp_Get_ABCForUser]
```

Comment: Cant i do that with table variable without using a temp table? I'm able to run this code perfectly in sql server 9.0. So does that mean 8.0 wont support this?

Comment: Correct.  I didn't realize they finally added this in; it will definitely NOT work in SQL 2K with a table variable.

Comment: if you are just retrieving 1 row, you might want to consider using OUTPUT parameters instead of returning a result set.

Comment: I'm retrieving multiple rows. I've created a temp table instead of using table variable. But the problem now is i'm not able to call the remote stored procedure. I've updated the problem in the question.